# Not able to create site collection in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, windows-authentication

I have created New Web application using PowerShell with Windows Authentication mode using `spadmin` account. Application successfully created. but when I try to do create Site collection for the same Web application, I get error saying:

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

`spadmin` account is in farm administrator group, Managed account, Administrator on computer,
site collection administrator.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you open another site with same user account? May be browser is logging with some other account on your site.

Comment: I am able to open the central admin with same account

Comment: Try changing the site collection administrator of that site to some other user using central admin. Then try with that user. May be there is some authentication issue with the site.

Comment: to change the site collection administrator, we need site collection right? site collection is not getting created only

Comment: Sorry , may be i misunderstood your question. so you are not able to create the site collection. Have you tried creating your web application manually from central administration.

Comment: yes.its working fine when I do it manually

Comment: Couple of questions, what i understand you able to create Site collection but when trying to browse it get the access denied, correct? what template you are using for the site collection?

Comment: No.while creating only I get that error. site collection doesn't get created. I am using team site template

Comment: Try using some other user as site collection admin. If it works change the site collection admin to your farm admin

Comment: Also try : http://www.drisky.co.uk/2013/05/29/sharepoint-2013-sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you/

Comment: yeah I did that it gt created successfully but it displays login name as System account which might create problem while publishing workflows from designer?

Comment: where you saw the login name as system account? on Central Admin, if yes then its normal because you are login with system account (SPadmin). who is the primary site & secondary site collections admins? when you publish a work flow to this site collection you will use site collection admin user account not the services account.

Comment: I saw it in my site. not in central admin. I think it is because I have created the application pool with the same account and used same account for site collection admin.

Comment: ok then you have to change the site collection admin from system account to your user account, from central admin > application management > change site collection adminsitrator

Comment: that I know. but I want to keep the site collection as same account name. il create application pool with different account. that should solve my problem I guess?

Comment: can i ask why you want the App Pool account same as Site collection admins? this is neither recommend nor best practice. App pool account should be a services account, it should separate form the regular user account.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a managed path, now you actually need to create a site collection under this managed path. So you should name the site collection url something like "http://sharepoint2010/teams/testsite.

Follwoing should be the PS command:

```
New-SPSite -URL "http://sharepoint2010/teams/testsite" -ownerAlias "sp\svc_spadmin" -Template "STS#0"
```

Moreover, the correct way of creating the managed path is

```
New-SPManagedPath –RelativeURL "Teams" -WebApplication "http://sharepoint2010/"
```

The above script will create wild card inclusion, If you want explicit inclusion just add
-Explicit

Answer (score 0):

Are opening your site in mozilla? If so please delete cookies and try to open in Internet Explorer. I have faced the same issue, and it is opening in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I am opening it in Internet Explorer only

Answer (score 0):

Which site templte are you using? :

1. Custom Site Template : maybe this site template tries to add something to Taxonomy service or User Profile and the account you use does not have permission to this service
2. Is it publishing ? : Publishing sites uses managed navigation, and same problem as 1, if the account does nto have proper permissions, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's this user policy thing: [see this technet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_republic/2013/10/18/sharepoint-2013-all-users-sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you/)

> Solution: If you set the Super User & Reader Accounts to a domain
>   account for the Web Application(s) using PowerShell, make sure they
>   have been added to the Web Application(s) via Central Admin with the
>   appropriate rights.
>
> More Information: By default, the Portal Super User account is the
>   site’s System Account, and the Portal Super Reader account is NT
>   Authority\Local Service.
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing to the site's setting page (http://server/site/_layouts/settings.aspx), or the All Site Content page (http://server/site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx).

This will tell you if the problem is with the home page, or with the site as a whole.  For example if you can browse to Settings or All Site Content, then there is a problem with the home page.

You can then edit the page in Web Parts Maintenance mode (https://demantprasad.wordpress.com/category/how-to-go-to-the-sharepoint-page-webpart-maintenance-mode/ has some info on how to get to it), and remove any Web Parts that might be problematic.